# Facebook plugin android phonegap

Tags: cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm new with phone gap please provide me code to connect with Facebook through phone gap
thanks.I don't know how to use Facebook plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following github.Hope this helps

```
https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/
```

Answer (score 0):

use facebook plugin - [check this](https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-facebook-connect)